# problem while running executable jar file

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have converted my Java program to executable jar file but while executing jar file it is giving error:

```
unable to initialize main class Combine".
caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:jxl/read/biff/BiffException.
```

Program is compiled and executed perfectly but after converting to jar file and while executing jar it is giving above error.

I have set my class path as:

```
classpath=%classpath%C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\javamail_api\javax.mail-1.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\javamail_api\activation.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\jexcelapi\jxl.jar;.;
```

Comment: What command are you running to execute the jar file ?

Comment: Is jxl/read/biff/BiffException included in your jar?

Comment: How did you create the jar file?

Comment: I have created jar file by using the following commands in command prompt:echo Main-Class: Combine > manifest.txt
jar cmf manifest.txt FinalExecutable.jar  Combine.class

Comment: Are you using any third party library

Comment: Please refer the following url to set classpath. The problem is in classpath set. https://mshappylearning.wordpress.com/2014/08/31/java-path-and-classpath-settings-on-windows-command-prompt-system-variables/

Replace the path with your actual folder location

Comment: Thank you for providing link, I have set classpath as described but error did not resolved;I am using the command "java -jar FinalExecutable.jar" for executing the jar file.

Comment: Do jar -tvf FinalExecutable.jar - check if the jar contains jxl/read/biff/BiffException

Comment: No it does not jxl/read/biff/BiffException.It has META-INF/,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,Combine.class

Comment: Not to worry about it. http://qaru.site/questions/7518510/javaxelelexception-javalangnoclassdeffounderror-jxlreadbiffbiffexception 

I guess you are working with Excel related operations. It needs third party jar file. You should not create Executable jar without the "jxl" jar file.
You need to include the above said jar too. You can use eclipse ide to create runnable jar which will help you include its dependent jars.

Comment: Thank you@Vigneshwaran.I have used eclipse IDE and created my jar file it is running perfectly.